# dynamically displaying records from database in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova

I want to display the records from db table..I am doing this by the following code

```
var db = window.openDatabase("DataBase", "3.6.22", "test", 200000);
db.transaction(function(transaction)
          { 
      transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM FUND_DET WHERE POLICY_NUMBER="'+polno+'";',[],
           function(transaction, result) 
           { 
               if (result != null && result.rows != null) 
               {
                   //alert("in if");                    
                      for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
                 {
                   var row = result.rows.item(i); 
                  // document.getElementById('lb'+i).innerHTML=row.FUND_DESC;
                   var x=row.ALLOC_PERCNT;
                  // document.getElementById('t'+i).value=xx;
                   global[i]=row.FUND_DESC;
                   glob1=row.FUND_DESC;
                    $("#table").append("<tr><td>"+row.FUND_DESC+"</td><td><input type='text' id='t"+i+"' size='5' /></td><td><input type='text' size='5' /></td></tr>");
var x=$("#t"+i).val();                                                }

                       }

                   },errorHandler); 
      },errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

As shown above i want  to assign id's for input tags which are in table tag.So that later i want to use the id's to set the values or to set the values.But id's are not assigning to input tags..Please tell me how to assign id's dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDYX7/) and it seems to be assigning the ID attribute correctly.

I'm assuming you want to assign the value of `x` to the `input` elements. Try this:

```
$('#t'+i).val(x);
```

Comment: If ids are assigned correctly i can able to set values as u said..But the id's are not assigned if i execute the code.Did that code work for u?

Comment: Yeah you be able to assign the values just after you append the HTML in `id='t"+i+"'`. The code worked for me in jsFiddle. Not sure what you actually have there though.